# Non lvalue in assignment error

Tags: c++, pointers, lvalue, rvalue

I got this error when I used `names` to print the strings, but no errors when `tempNames` is used.

```
char* names[] = { "JIM",
                  "RAM",
                  "SAM",
                  0  };
int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
{
    char** tempNames = names ;        
    while(*names != 0)
        std::cout << *names++ << std::endl ; 
    return 0;
}
```

How come `*names` became an rvalue whereas `*tempNames` is an lvalue.

Comment: `*names` is an lvalue. But you cannot do `names++`. That is where the problem is.

Comment: What makes you think that `*names` is an rvalue? Can you post some code to support that claim?

Answer (score 0):

As [Bill Lynch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47453/bill-lynch) explains in the comments you're incrementing type `char* []` that's not allowed. (It's easier if you think of it as type `int []`.) When you assign to a `char**` then you can increment it.

Or a better C++ iterator based solution C++11:

```
char* names[] = { "JIM",
                  "RAM",
                  "SAM" };


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char** tempNames = names ;

    for(auto i = std::begin(names); i != std::end(names); ++i){
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you going to give a modern c++ variant, at least go all out: https://gist.github.com/sharth/10f767045f2fe335f95c

Comment: @BillLynch I agree that he should use `std::string` but I didn't want it to be unclear that he could do this with `char*`s or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is differen, why *names++ is an rvalue, and *tempNames++ is an lvalue?

Comment: @Manesh Right if you use an iterator you'll find it will solve your problem. I'm honestly having a little trouble understanding why. I think it's the increment is confusing to the compiler somehow. Well and the iterator's just better syntax anyway, so there's that.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Here's the reduced code: `int x[5]; x++;` which causes a compiler error: _cannot increment value of type 'int [5]'_

Comment: @BillLynch Hmmm... I see what you're saying that compiler error is a bit misleading. I got the r-value error too. The real problem is that type `char* []` can't be moved. I'm getting around that by creating an iterator. You should add that as an answer, or I can edit mine.

Comment: @BillLynch It's marked as duplicate now, which I think means that you can't add answers, so I just edited mine.